OpenAI Assistant Streaming Issue with Nextjs 14
I am using OpenAi Assistant  with Streaming in nodejs it is working fine with express but same thing i want to try with Nextjs 14 it is giving me response undefined Check the code below
NodeJs Working Code Example:
Response
Hello,How i can i can help you Today!

Code:
import OpenAI from "openai";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const openai = new OpenAI();
const assistantId = process.env.ASSISTANT_ID;

async function main(message) {
  const assistant = await openai.beta.assistants.retrieve(assistantId);

  const thread = await openai.beta.threads.create();
  await openai.beta.threads.messages.create(thread.id, {
    role: "user",
    content: message,
  });
  const stream = await openai.beta.threads.runs.create(thread.id, {
    assistant_id: assistantId,
    stream: true,
  });

  let responseContent = [];

  for await (const event of stream) {
    //console.log(event);
    if (event.event === "thread.message.delta") {
      // Accumulate the content from the delta event
      responseContent.push(...event.data.delta.content);
    } else if (event.event === "thread.message.completed") {
      // Print out the final response when the message is completed
      const finalResponse = responseContent
        .map((part) => part.text?.value || "")
        .join("");

      return finalResponse;
    }
  }
}

const runMain = async (message) => {
  const response = await main(message);
  console.log(response);
  return response;
};

// const message = "What you can help me with";
// runMain(message);

export default runMain;

Nextjs 14 Code Response:
Listening to Stream
Processing Stream
Response from main: undefined
Final response text: undefined

Code:
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import {NextResponse} from 'next/server';
import OpenAI from 'openai';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const openai = new OpenAI();
const assistantId = process.env.ASSISTANT_ID;

// Adjusting to use proper Next.js API route signature
export  async function POST(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return res.status(405).json({ error: 'Method Not Allowed' });
  }

  try {
    const { message } =await req.json();
    console.log('Received message:', message);
    const responseText = await runMain(message);
    console.log('Final response text:', responseText);
    return NextResponse.json( {responseText} );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in POST function:', error);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Failed to process your request.' });
  }
}

async function main(message) {
  console.log('Retrieving Assistant');
  const assistant = await openai.beta.assistants.retrieve(assistantId);
  console.log('Assistant Retrieved:', assistant.id);

  const thread = await openai.beta.threads.create();
  console.log('Thread Created:', thread.id);

  await openai.beta.threads.messages.create(thread.id, {
    role: "user",
    content: message,
  });

  console.log('Creating Stream');
  const stream = await openai.beta.threads.runs.create(thread.id, {
    assistant_id: assistantId,
    stream: true,
  });
console.log('Stream Created:', stream);
  let responseContent = [];
  console.log('Listening to Stream');
  try {
    console.log('Processing Stream');
    for await (const event of stream) {
      //console.log('Received event:', event.event);
      if (event.event === "thread.message.delta") {
        console.log('Received message:', event.data.text?.value);
        responseContent.push(event.data.text?.value || "");
      }
      if (event.event === "thread.message.completed") {
        console.log('Stream completed');
        console.log('Final response content:', responseContent);
        const finalResponse = responseContent.join("");
        console.log('Final response:', finalResponse);
        return finalResponse;
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Stream processing error:', err);
    throw new Error('Failed to process the stream');
  }
}

async function runMain(message) {
  const response = await main(message);
  console.log('Response from main:', response);
  return response;
}

Nextjs 14 is serverless is there anyway to use nodejs inside of Nextjs or what is the best way so i can get the streaming response in nextjs-14
I have tried it using nodejs and its was working fine but i dont know why it is not working with nextjs 14 i am new to nextjs 14 so its really challenging for me.
